# File not fond exception when trying to download apk file

Tags: android, iis-7

I have an android apk file hosted in iis 7 which I would like to download and install from within an android app. I am relying heavily on the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically), but I am getting a fileNotFound exception at `InputStream is = con.getInputStream();`

I am able to download the apk file from within a browser both on my desktop and on the phone (Samsung galaxy Nexus) and I have added the apk mime type to iis.

Here is my code.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://android.atomweb.net.au/CasLite.apk");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }

            fos.close();
            is.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")),
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }
```

When I post a break point in and look and the connection response code after the connection has been made but before the getInputStream, its 405.

Comment: Try [adding MIME type apk in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be a GET, not a POST?

Comment: Yeah, I should be. I have tried it with both verbs and I get the same result.